# HTMLButtonObject stored in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, xml, button

My current code is directly below. Everything works except my button function.

The one line that is giving me issues is the

```
var tesbut = new onclickfunc(buttons[g], 'testbuttloc');
```

line. I believe this is because I cannot make the buttons[g] into an HTMLButtonElement which is why I have this line.

```
buttons[g].setAttribute("type", "HTMLButtonElement");
```

I believe that I need the line directly above because whenever I use

```
var tesbut = new onclickfunc(testbutt, 'testbuttloc');
```

it works. (These are the names of the variables that are declared in XML) So, is there any advice?

```
     var buttons = [];
     var subbuttons = [];         

      for(var mainsplunkcount = 0; mainsplunkcount<mx.length; mainsplunkcount++){
            buttons[mainsplunkcount] = mx[mainsplunkcount].getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;       
            subbuttons[mainsplunkcount] =mx[mainsplunkcount].getElementsByTagName("BUTTONLOC")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            mainnewstat.id = mainstatus[mainsplunkcount];
            $("<div />", { "class":"Main_Category", id:"product"+group[mainsplunkcount] })
            $("<button />", { id:buttons[mainsplunkcount] })
            //divs that work
            .append($('</button>'))
            .append($('</div>'))
            .appendTo(main_sort[mainsplunkcount]);
            $("<div />", { id:subbuttons[mainsplunkcount], "class" : "hidden"})
            .append($('<div class="group"><font size="2">' + maingroup[mainsplunkcount] + '</div></div>'))
            .append($('</div>'))
            .appendTo(main_sort[mainsplunkcount]);
      }




      //dropdown for submenus of menus
      var onclickfunc = function(button, newpost){
        button.onclick = function(){
           var div = document.getElementById(newpost);
           if(div.style.display !== 'none'){ 
              div.style.display = 'none';
           } else{
              div.style.display = 'inline';
           } 
         };
      };

      for(var g = 0; g<mx.length; g++){
        buttons[g].setAttribute("type", "HTMLButtonElement");
        var tesbut = new onclickfunc(buttons[g], 'testbuttloc');
      }
```

XML code

```
<MAINCONTAINER>
    <GROUP>Test</GROUP>
    <INOUT>test</INOUT>
    <CRITICALITY>test</CRITICALITY>
    <CALLNUMBER>6</CALLNUMBER>
    <LOCATION>sortAll5</LOCATION>
    <STATUSNAME>testt</STATUSNAME>
    <BUTTON>testbutt</BUTTON>
    <BUTTONLOC>testbuttloc</BUTTONLOC>
```